Why is gdb showing wrong source files?
I am build code for a cortex-m0 using arm-none-eabi.  My project has lots of functions removed using the -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections options.  When I start stepping into my code I found that gdb was showing the wrong source, specifically it will show code for functions that were removed (never called).
I did some debugging and noticed that if I use GCC 11 or newer this happens but GCC 10 appears to work correctly.  I also found that if I use objdump -dlr to dump the problematic elf files I get something like this:
00000000 <exception_table>:
getStackSize():
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/CMSIS/wlr089/source/gcc/startup_wlr089.c:244
   0:   ff 7f 00 20 95 04 00 00 5d 05 00 00 9d 05 00 00     ... ....].......
    ...
getStackUsed():
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/CMSIS/wlr089/source/gcc/startup_wlr089.c:254
  2c:   5d 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5d 05 00 00     ]...........]...
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/CMSIS/wlr089/source/gcc/startup_wlr089.c:257
  3c:   c5 08 00 00 5d 05 00 00 f9 0b 00 00 65 06 00 00     ....].......e...
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/CMSIS/wlr089/source/gcc/startup_wlr089.c:250
  4c:   5d 05 00 00 5d 05 00 00 5d 05 00 00 5d 05 00 00     ]...]...]...]...
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/CMSIS/wlr089/source/gcc/startup_wlr089.c:267
  5c:   5d 05 00 00 99 07 00 00 bd 07 00 00 e1 07 00 00     ]...............
  6c:   05 08 00 00 29 08 00 00 4d 08 00 00 5d 05 00 00     ....)...M...]...
_ZN10I2C_MASTER4syncEv():
D:\Projects\SECA\LoRa\firmware/src/drivers/i2c_master/i2c_master.cpp:90
  7c:   5d 05 00 00 5d 05 00 00 e9 09 00 00 29 0a 00 00     ]...].......)...
_ZN10I2C_MASTER18setCommandBitsWireEh():

All the references above are bogus, for example getStackSize() is not in the binary.  What I can roughly determine is that GCC 11 and later appears to be placing all the code that was remove using -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections at address 0x0000. This appears to cause gdb to incorrectly think source code near address 0x0000 is from functions that have been removed.
I even tried to use readelf to dump all the symbols readelf -a and when doing this the getStackSize symbol is not in the output.
I keep doubting myself that this is a bug in GCC 11+ as it has been out for ~3 years now.  As such I am wondering if I am doing something wrong?
